# loop through html element of common class in jquery

Tags: jquery, each

I am working on 'add more' functionality in jQuery where user clicks on "+" symbol then extra group of div elements will be added along with number for each div, suppose let's say if user has to add multiple "companies", by click on add more button company2, company3, company4, etc. will be added. as usually after click on '+' to add more companies user also clicks on '-' symbol to remove the respective company. what my problem here is if user adds 5 companies if he removes company-3 then the company number need to be updated based on total company count present, if removes 3 then order should be 1,2,3,4.

```js
//Add Company Script:

var cn=$("#experience_latest_value").val();
$(".add_experience").click(function(){
  var new_experience = '<div class="col-md-12"><div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Company:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" name="company[]" id="company">
 </div></div></div>';

var new_experience1 = '<div class="row"><a class="pull-right remove_experience btn btn-danger" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a><div class="col-md-12"><h3>Company '+cn+': </h3></div>'+new_experience+'</div>';
$("#experience_latest_value").val(++cn);
$(".append_experience").append(new_experience1);
  
//Remove Company Script:

$('.append_experience').on('click', '.remove_experience', function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
  var cnum = 2;
  $('.remove_experience.col-md-12>h3').each(function() {
    $(this).val(cnum);
    cnum++;
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="panel-title"><input type="checkbox" name="experience_check" id="experience_check" checked="checked" class="check_cls all_experiences" value="on">
  <label for="experience_check" class="checkc"></label> 
  Experience: 
  <a class="pull-right add_experience  btn btn-success">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
  </a>
</h2>
<div class="tab-pane active" role="tabpanel" id="step2">
<div class="append_experience">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <h3>
      <input type="checkbox" name="individual_experience[]" id="individual_experience71" class="check_cls individual_experience" checked>
      <label for="individual_experience71" class="checkc"></label> 
      Company 1: 
    </h3>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="experience_latest_value" id="experience_latest_value" value="">
  
<!-- START: This script added dynamically after click on '+' -->
   <div class="row">
     <a class="pull-right remove_experience btn btn-danger" data-cnumber="3">
       <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
     </a>
     <div class="col-md-12">
       <h3>Company 2: </h3>
     </div>
      <div class="col-md-12"></div>
    </div>
<!-- END: This script added dynamically after click on '+' -->

</div> <!-- append_experience -->
</div>
```

All the extra added companies will have the class "remove_experience", the first company doesn't have 'remove_experience' class. Whats wrong in my code. Anyone please assist. Thanks.

Comment: I think it should be `$('.remove_experience').each(function(){$(this).next().find('h3').text(cnum) })`

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks @Satpal

Answer (score 0):

Please Try This

```
$('.append_experience').on('click','.remove_experience',function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
  var cnum = 2;
  $('.remove_experience.col-md-12>h3').each(function(){
    $(this).html(cnum);
    cnum++;
  });
});
```